# How to reinitialise init(); in React to allow Adobe Animate SVG file to rerun upon route change?

Tags: reactjs, adobe-animate

I have set up a simple react project that has a reusable component called 'cover'. Within the 'cover' component, I have an animated SVG I created from Adobe Animate and have it exported into HTML, JS and SVG. This works fine on first load as the JS is in the public/index.html file and initialised in the  tag. However, when I change routes, the init isn't retriggered (which is correct since React isn't meant to reload the page), so now I have the dilemma of not being able to see the SVG upon route changes.

See example here: https://react-sfj7qx.stackblitz.io

Editor version: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-sfj7qx

Note that the init() function on the  tag doesn't seem to render within Stackblitz...

Comment: Can you please put it on https://stackblitz.com

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @JonathanLafleur, I've added it in but it looks like the init() function isn't accepted within stackblitz.com but you can see the code there: https://react-sfj7qx.stackblitz.io

Comment: Can you share the editor, please? Would be easier...

Comment: Sorry, yes @JonathanLafleur, I'm pretty newb with the React world

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't know Adobe Animation too much, I edited your stackblitz, I break your code a little bit, but you have all it needs to succeed in this code. What you was not aware of, is that you need to import and export function and variable between files in react. So you'll see how I've done it in the stackblitz example.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! I can't seem to load the link with your changes, the code appears the same, am I missing something?

Comment: Omg, It looks like I haven't saved... Let me check that again -.-

Comment: I don't see any animation, maybe you can tell me more about it ?

Comment: The init(); triggers and loads the animation via the <script> added in the index.js file in the <head>. The animation itself is from 'assets/js/svg.js' which is also loaded in the index.js file. The animation is also dependent on this library '<script src="https://code.createjs.com/createjs-2015.11.26.min.js"></script>'. So Adobe Animate generates the html file that imports the dependency library, the svg.js file and the init code to start up the animation loop and some other responsive sizing behaviour.... Hope this makes sense